# Obtener valores time de la Base de Datos y guardarlos en una variable en php

Tags: php, sql, datetime

Tengo dos campos de tipo time en la BBDD: inicio y fin.

para acceder a ellos y obtener su valor, hago lo siguiente:

```
    public function calcular_duracion($id)
{
    //$sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, inicio, fin) from reunion where id=.$id");
    $consulta = $this->db->prepare('SELECT inicio, fin FROM reunion WHERE ID=:id');
    $consulta->bindValue('id', $id);
    $consulta->execute();
    $reunion = $consulta->fetch();
    $reunionRecuperado = new Reunion();
    $inicioR = $reunionRecuperado->setInicio($reunion['inicio']);
    $finR = $reunionRecuperado->setFin($reunion['fin']);
    $inicio=$reunionRecuperado->getInicio($inicioR);
    $fin=$reunionRecuperado->getFin($finR);

    $inicioF = new DateTime($inicio);
    $finF = new DateTime($fin);
    $duracion = $inicioF->diff($finF);

    return $duracion;
}
```

Después, llamo al método desde el modelo de la siguiente manera:

```
//Línea 124
 <?php echo $dao->calcular_duracion($id)?>
```

Y esto me devuelve el siguiente error:

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string in reunionModelo.php on line 124.

Debo convertir el resultado en string?? Si es así, cómo?

Ayuda por favor!!

Una vez resuelta la duda anterior, trato de obtener el intervalo de tiempo en minutos. Tras la linea $duracion = $inicio->diff($fin); escribo lo siguiente:

```
$duracion->format('H:i:s');
    list($horas, $minutos) = explode(':', $duracion);
    $hora_en_minutos = ($horas * 60) + $minutos;     

    return $hora_en_minutos;
```

Y esto me da el siguiente error:

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in model/reunionDAO.php on line 165.

Presumo que es porque la función diff no me está devolviendo un string... Pero he intentado formatearlo y me sigue dando error...

Comment: Tal cual lo estas haciendo a mi me funciona, lo único los format sobre inicio y fin son inecesario si no los vas a utilizar. Debería aplicar format ya sea a $duracion, $inicio o $fin cuando lo vayas a imprimir.

Comment: si haces un return $duracion y luego un echo del método te imprime la diferencia entre horas?

Comment: A `$duracion` para imprimirlo hay que darle formato ejemplo `echo $duracion->format(%h);` esto me muestra las horas de diferencia

Comment: Perfecto!!! Ahora sí!!! Muchas gracias!!! ¿Y sabrías cómo hacer para que la función diff me calcule todo en minutos?

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es la diferencia en segundos creo que el mejor camino es calcularla directamente sin utilizar diff, ejemplo: `$inicio = new DateTime($inicio); $fin = new DateTime($fin); $diffSegundos = $fin->format('U') - $inicio->format('U');`

Comment: El error que muestras en la última edición  es que estas retornando un objeto y echo no lo puede imprimir, si quieres retornar un String para que se imprima hazlo con `$duracion->format('mi formato')` como comentamos antes.

Comment: Sí, muchísimas gracias!! Eso está solucionado.

Comment: El problema es que necesito guardar ese intervalo de tiempo en una variable y en minutos porque luego quiero operar con ellos como si fueran un entero. De momento estoy tratando de devolver los minutos como string y luego los convertiré a enteros... Para obtenerlos en string estoy haciendo lo siguiente (edito para que se vea)...

Comment: Ya casi lo tengo, solo necesito convertir los DateTime en Strings... Haré una nueva pregunta para no liar más esta.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la diferencia en segundos de 2 fecha puedes utilizar el método `DateTime::format` para retornar el tiempo en unix y luego restarlos, ejemplo:

```
<?php

$inicio = new DateTime('09:00:00');
$fin = new DateTime('10:00:59');

// restar las fechas en formato unix
$diffSegundos = $fin->format('U') - $inicio->format('U');

// mostrar total segundos
echo $diffSegundos; // 3659

// mostrar total minutos y segundos sobrantes
echo (intval($diffSegundos / 60)) . ' min ' . ($diffSegundos % 60) . ' seg'; // 60 min 59 seg
?>
```

En lo último que muestras estas pasando directamente `$duracion` que es un objeto no un string, pues no estas almacenando lo que retorna `$duracion->format('H:i:s')` en ningun lugar. Aparte de esto el formato que estas pasando no es válido, debes tener en cuenta que los formatos de `DateInterval::format` no son los mismos que de un `DateTime::format`. Deberías hacer algo así:

```
$inicio = new DateTime('09:00:00');
$fin = new DateTime('10:00:59');
$duracion = $inicio->diff($fin);

// Ajustamos el format y guardamos el resultado en $date
$date = $duracion->format('%H:%i:%s');
// al explode pasamos el resultado del format
list($horas, $minutos) = explode(':', $date);
$hora_en_minutos = ($horas * 60) + $minutos;     

return $hora_en_minutos; // 60
```